I am having a hard time getting an object to rotate and move in the object's new forward direction
Why is my player still moving forward(north) in world coordinates? I want the player to face and move in a new direction. Please explain in simple terms.

void PlayerMover()
{
    _step = _speed * _speedMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;

    PlayerBoost();
    float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    PlayerRotation();

    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(-vertical, 0, 0);
    transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    transform.position += direction * _step;
}

I am using C#/UNITY
extra characters to satisfy minimum 220 character limit

we have 2 different directions in unity. vector.direction and transfrom.direction.
the Vector3.forward you used is gonna alway point at global z value. you should use transform.forward to make your character to go to its own forward direction.
Update(){
     Vector3 moveVector=transform.forward*speed;
     transform.Translate(moveVector * Time.deltaTime;
}


with the line:     Vector3 moveVector = transform.forward* speed;     are you converting the players transform to global coordinates/direction?

@eyetengu the transform.forward converts the local forward of the object to the global forward. multiplying by speed makes it a vector in direction and size of the desired movement

I am unsure what I am doing wrong and I seem unable to add screenshots to my post. smh. I will attach the code in another comment.

public class PlayerMoverIntermediate : MonoBehaviour
{
float _speed = 3.0f;
float _step;
void Update()
{ _step = _speed * Time.deltaTime;
    PlayerMover(); }

void PlayerMover()
{ float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0, 0, vertical);
transform.Rotate(0, horizontal * _step *10, 0);
    transform.TransformDirection(transform.forward);
    transform.position += direction * _step;
}

}

sorry for the mashed up code. It was too long so I took out a bunch of 'white space'

@eyetengu dont move in your direction variable. you have already rotated by it. just instead of direction in the last line of code, use transform.forward

Is there a way to add a screenshot to a comment?


well, that didnt work
